# Previous/Next Post Within the Category?

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I want to add a code in my theme to show a Next/Previous link below the post but within the same category. I Don't need a thumbnail but if possible I would appreciated, still that's not important right now. Right now I just want to insert a code(s) to one of my PHP scripts so that it would show a next/previous link in the post.

I search on google and find some stuff But I don't know how to use them. 
For example, I don't know how's the next_posts_link or previous_posts_link works. Because my theme don't have the LOOP.

I use many plugins but soe doesn't work for me and the one that work doesn't show on Mobile version. Right now the one that work for me is the **WP Single Post Navigation Within Category** Plugin.

My website is a Movie Episode site so I want to be able to let visitors to click next to the next episode within the same Series/Category.

If there's anything you can help please, Help.

Answer (score 2):

There are the core functions [`next/previous_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) that accept several arguments. The 3<sup>rd</sup> is the one that triggers `in_same_cat`. So if you set that one to `TRUE`, then you'll only get posts that are in filed under the same category.

Comment: What will happen if the post has more than one categories?

Comment: @sanjithedward When you look at the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/#source-code), then you see that it uses `get_var()` in the end, which returns only one single field from a row. Meaning if there are multiple return matches, it returns only the first match. You could still use the filters to fetch other related posts.